# Disable scientific notation in hover tool Bokeh

Tags: hover, bokeh, interactive, scientific-notation

It seems like there are plenty of answers on how to disable the scientific notation in Bokeh on numbers displayed on x and y axis. But how about disabling it for the hover tool?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it, at least for my particular case it was sufficient to force the hover tool to read it as an integer:

```
hover.tooltips = [("Date", "@Date"),  ("Volume", "@z{int}")]
```

Comment: Hi, if that solved the problem you should accept you own answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

Suppress the scientific notation by making the hover tool read the particular variable as a number with predetermined decimal digits by adding {1,11...} next to the variable name.

In this case it is 2 digits for volume:

```
hover.tooltips = [("Date", "@Date"),  ("Volume", "@volume{1,11}")]
```